# Unhandled exception in C# talking to C++ CLI Wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, .net

We have a C# application that calls a number of methods in a C++ CLI wrapper DLL; this in turn calls a number of unmanaged functions in a 3rd party DLL that we have no access to.

The code blocks in the C# are 100% sat within a try, Catch(Exception e) block, but we have just had a unhanded exception pop up.

Looking at the event log on the server, the final part of the stack trace was the method on the wrapper app.

There is no threading or anything like that in our part of the application, so i can only assume that there is something happening in the 3rd Party DLL that is causing the issue.

How can i structure this so that all exceptions are handled?

Update: The exception that is being thrown is a System.AccessViolationException

Comment: Could be a CSE or SOE, native code itself will failfast on the really nasty stuff.  Reporting it could be very simple to do or could be impossible to do.  Intentionally not telling us what you know about it is a very unproductive way to ask for help.

Comment: i have updated the question with the exception that is being thrown. Did not realise that it was relevant!

Comment: Did you read the section "AccessViolationException and try/catch blocks"? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shared by Johan:

> **AccessViolationException and try/catch blocks**
>
> Starting with the .NET
> Framework 4, AccessViolationException exceptions thrown by the common
> language runtime are not handled by the catch statement in a
> structured exception handler if the exception occurs outside of the
> memory reserved by the common language runtime. To handle such an
> AccessViolationException exception, you should apply the
> HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute to the method
> in which the exception is thrown.